# hive accesses orc external table by position rather than column name

Tags: hive, presto, orc

I'm using `Hive 3.1.0` cluster on `HDInsights 4.0`.

The orc and parquet with the same data were created using spark, with schema `(a string, b int, c string)`.

> create external table a_st_b_int_d_st_orc(a string, b int, d string) stored as orc location `<path_to_spark_created_files>`
>
> select * from `a_st_b_int_d_st_orc`;
>
> ```
> +----+----+------+
> | a  | b  |  d   |
> +----+----+------+
> | 1  | 2  | abc  |
> | 2  | 3  | bcd  |
> +----+----+------+
> ```
>
> create external table a_st_b_int_d_st_parquet(a string, b int, d string) stored as parquet 
>     location `<path_to_spark_created_files>`
>
> select * from `a_st_b_int_d_st_parquet`;
>
> ```
> +----+----+-------+
> | a  | b  |   d   |
> +----+----+-------+
> | 1  | 2  | NULL  |
> | 2  | 3  | NULL  |
> +----+----+-------+
> ```

```
The default behavior of hive native ORC-Reader is that it maps meta-store column names by position with orc files.    
There were JIRAs created to map columns by name and reverted as well.
```

The behavior wrt parquet can be configured using `parquet.column.index.access` although default being column resolution by name.

In Presto also we can specify `hive.orc.use-column-names=true`

How to turn this off the default ORC behavior in hive?

Comment: orc.force.positional.evolution=true if default on hive 3.x, if disabled orc reader would map rows based on column name mapping instead of index postition.